# Did Lord Rama show Vishwaroopa Darshan to Sati Devi?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, rama, shiva-purana, sati-goddess

I know Krishna showed his Vishwaroopa Darshna during Mahabharatha War. But [Shiva Puranam by DSR Anjaneyulu](http://ebooks.tirumala.org/Product/?ID=540), which was translated to English from Telugu by RM Chella says, Rama had shown Vishwaroopa Darshan to Sati Devi.

> As Sati bowed to Rama, he said: “O Mother, what made you, the wife of Siva, assume the form of my wife? What is the reason behind you
>   leaving your husband and roaming in this wild jungle? Don’t you know
>   that this place is full of demons? Please be welladvised and go back
>   to Mount Kailasa”. Sati Devi was amazed. She regretted her ruse, and
>   fell prostrate at Rama’s feet, begging his pardon. Then Lakshmana also
>   realised the truth and the might of his divine brother.
>
> Then Lord Rama displayed his **universal manifestation** to Sati Devi.
>   Sati was struck with reverential
>   awe, and sang the Lord’s praises: “Lord, I am able to see the entire
>   world of creation in Thee. There! I can see the sun and the moon; the
>   Lord Creator Brahma, the Lord Siva Himself; the thirty million gods in
>   you. In a trillion forms of creatures, with their countless arms and
>   faces and feet, art Thou now mirrored. Thou art indeed the Alpha and
>   the Omega of all creation, and yet Thou hast be beginning or middle or
>   end. I discern the infinitely iridiscent transfiguration of Thine
>   spreading itself in the multiplicity of the Rudras, Aadityas, Vasus,
>   Saadhyas, Asvins, Maruts, Gandharvas, Yakshas and the Titans--- all of
>   whom are now gazing at Thine awe-inspiring Light of lights. Oh Lord of
>   grace and mercy, I Knew not Thine absolute power in my former
>   ignorance; now I realise Thine undening glory; so on my bended knees I
>   beseech Thy forgiveness”.
>
> Lord Siva told Sati: “You have been very fortunate to be able to see
>   that great god’s **Vishvarupa**. You were indeed for ever sanctified by
>   being addressed as ‘Mother by that supreme being. Now, since Vishnu,
>   Brahma and myself are brotherly facets of one and the same Invisible
>   Existence reflected in the Trinity, virtually you are my brother,
>   too!”.

But Vishwaroopa Darshan wasn't mentioned in [this unabridged](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3830/3500) Shiva Purana.

Did Rama show Vishwaroopa Darshan to Sati Devi?

Comment: Story of Sati meeting Rama was mentioned in Shiva purana but there was no mention of Vishwaroopa Darshan. Was Vishwaroopa Darshan mentioned in Ram Charit Manas?

Comment: Yes, Tulasidas does mention the Vishwarupa.  But I think the Shiva Purana is the only scripture that even mentions the story Shakti meeting Rama, so I don' think Rama showing Shatkti his Vishwarupa has a scriptural basis.  By the way, I think this may be an interpolation in the Suva Purana, because the chronology doesn't make sense; Kartikeya was born long before the 24th Mahayuga of the Vaivasvata Manvanatara.  In fact the story of Kartikeya is mentioned in the Bala Kanda of the Ramayana!

Comment: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9188/3500 i have asked this question relating to it.

Comment: Well, at Tulasidas places this Sati incident in the story of the most recent Ramayana.  In any case, I think the only scripture that mentions the Ramayana ever taking place before the most recent one is the Padma Purana.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan There's no incident of Rama Showing Vishwaroopa in [Ramacharitamanas](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7T0zBCVuV7cR055dEFfNFRNQ28/view?pref=2&pli=1)

Comment: @TheDestroyer "Virtually you are my brother too!" How can Sati be brother of Shiv ?

Comment: In RCM there is an incident but it is not the expected vishwaroopa where all the 14 worlds are within rama etc. He shows this form to kakabhusanda. A different type of supremacy is displayed to sati devi.

Answer (score 5):

The Vishvarupa darshana does not find mention in the [Shiva Purana by Gita press](https://archive.org/details/SHIVPURANHINDI/page/n169/mode/2up) too. Yet, a similar incident in a similar sequence finds mention in the Ramcharitmanas by Tulsidas.

We can say it is slightly modified version of vishvarupa compared to what Shri Krishna shows Arjuna. It is a form of Shri Rama in which many Brahmas, Vishnus, Shivas, other devatas of different forms, and all the different types of chara achara life forms are worshipping Shri Rama and Sita.

The story: Sati is anguished and thinks as to what she will tell Mahadeva about testing Shri Rama when she returns. Thereafter:

> I heeded not the word of Shankara and imposed My own ignorance on Rama. What reply shall I give to my lord now? The agony of Her heart was most terrible. Shri Rama perceived that Sati had got vexed; He, therefore, revealed to Her a part of His glory. As She went on Her way Sati beheld a strange phenomenon. Rama was going ahead of Her alongwith His Consort, Sita, and His younger brother, Lakshmana. She looked back and there too She saw the Lord with His brother and Sita in an attractive garb. Whichever way She turned Her eyes, there was the Lord enthroned with the Siddhas (adepts) and illumined sages ministering to Him. Sati saw more than one sets of Shiva, Brahma and Vishnu, each set possessing a glory infinitely greater than that of the others. She also beheld a whole host of gods bowing at the Lord’s feet and waiting upon Him in their different garbs. 
>  - *Chaupais 1-4 of Doha 54*
>
> She further perceived innumerable Satis (consorts of Shiva), consorts of Brahma and Lakshmis (consorts of Vishnu), all peerless in beauty. They conformed in their appearance to the garb in which Brahmå and the other gods appeared. 
>  - *Doha 54*
>
> **Each separate vision of Rama was attended by a whole host of gods with their feminine counterparts, as well as by the whole animate and inanimate creation with its multitudinous species.** But while the gods who adored the Lord appeared in diverse garbs, the appearance of Shri Rama was the same in every case. Although She saw many Ramas with as many Sitas, their garb did not vary. Seeing the same Rama, the same Lakshmana and the same Sita, Sati was struck with great awe. Her heart quivered, and She lost all consciousness of Her body. Closing Her eyes she sat down on the wayside. When She opened Her eyes and gazed once more, the daughter of Daksha saw nothing there. Repeatedly bowing Her head at the feet of Shri Rama, She proceeded to the spot where the Lord of Kailasa was. 
>  - *Chaupais 1-4 of Doha 55*
>  [Balakanda of Shri Ramcharitmanas](https://www.astrojyoti.com/pdfs/ramacharitamanas/bal1-97.pdf)